# The 8 CPU of Core 0 at 100% us. Don't understand why

Tags: cpu-usage

Need help as i don't understand why the 8 CPU of Core 0 run at 100% us. 8 others Cpu on core 1 are normal.

The rigth column P on figure correspond to "Last Used CPU" order by Cpu asc.

Thank's for all suggestions

[image: screenshot of "top" command]

[An process sorted by TIME+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkPXO.png)

To reply to AlexD. There is no such optimisations on Elastic. Anyway, i stopped it, as Solr and Nginx. But always 100% on first 8 CPU.

The server run very nicely for a while.

Just a strange things some days ago :

I had a problem to connecting via ssh. Its strange `/usr/sbin/sshd` file changed from `root:root` to `root:user_i_use_to_connect`

And `lsattr` of /usr/sbin/sshd changed to `-u---a--------e----` instead of `--------------e----`

Comment: Sort processes by 'TIME+' column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply .
I just updated my original post to add the Screenshot of Process sorted by TIME+

Comment: If you use `htop` and enable `detailed CPU statistics` and `show userland threads`, what do you see then?

Comment: I wonder if someone 'optimized' the system and forced some subset of programs to run on the first 8 cores. Someone set elastic to run with nice 4. I would check it first.

Comment: Actually, it is the other way around. For some reason, only kernel tasks and `atop` have a value < 8 in the `P` column in the last `top` output and they are all in the lower half of `top`. But cores < 8 consume 98-100% of `us` not `system` so it is a userspace task running there. Hidden miner?

Comment: Thank you a lot Alex.
I will have a look to this way.
Sure i will learn a lot to try found it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the changes in the ownership and attributes of `/usr/sbin/sshd` suggests your system may have been hacked.

If so, that would probably explain the behavior of the CPUs too: your server might be running a 8-threaded coin miner, "hidden" by a rootkit of some sort.

[Please see this Server Fault question for advice on dealing with a compromised server.](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: Sorry, but where is the `sshd` exectuable and its ownership and attributes even mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Kusalananda They were mentioned in the non-answer posted by xspe that's been since hidden, and I tried to ask them to move the information into the question and delete the non-answer, but looks like only the deletion was done (new poster, unfamiliar with ways of SE). Since I can still see the hidden non-answer, I'll take the liberty of moving the info into the question.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Thanks telcoM.
As i'm beginner with stackexchange i did mistakes.
Hope next time i''ll be better.

Anyway, i found a lot of hidden files under /tmp. I've been hacked ! .